Is the intersection of these two polytopes included in their average polytope?
Let $\mathcal{P}, \mathcal{Q}, \mathcal{T}$ be three polytopes in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with equal number of facets and vertices. Let $\mathcal{U}$ denote the set of vertices of $\mathcal{P}$ and $\mathcal{V}$ denote the set of vertices of $\mathcal{Q}$. Assume w.l.o.g. that $\mathcal{U} \cap \mathcal{V} = \emptyset$, i.e. the polytopes $\mathcal{P}, \mathcal{Q}$ have no common vertex. Since $|\mathcal{U}| = |\mathcal{V}|$ let $N$ denote the number of their elements. Between the polytopes $\mathcal{P}$ and $\mathcal{Q}$ there are the following constraints:

Exists $\epsilon >0 $ such that:

for all $u \in \mathcal{U}$ one has $\mathcal{B}(u,2\cdot \epsilon) \cap \mathcal{U}\setminus \{u\} = \emptyset$ i.e. the vertices of $\mathcal{P}$ are farther apart by at least a distance of $2 \cdot \epsilon$.
for all $v \in \mathcal{V}$ one has $\mathcal{B}(v,2 \cdot \epsilon) \cap \mathcal{V}\setminus \{v\} = \emptyset$ i.e. the vertices of $\mathcal{Q}$ are farther apart by at least a distance of $2 \cdot \epsilon$.
for all $u \in \mathcal{U}$ one has $\mathcal{B}(u,\epsilon) \cap \mathcal{V}\neq  \emptyset$ i.e. for each vertex of $\mathcal{P}$ there is exactly one vertex of $\mathcal{Q}$ at a distance closer than $\epsilon$.


Because of the previous assumption, we can form the pairs $(u_k, v_k)$ for all $k \in \{1, ..., N\}$. It is known that either $u_k \in \mathcal{Q}$ or $v_k \in \mathcal{P}$.


Define $\mathcal{T}$ as the polytope with the vertices
$$
 w_k = \frac{u_k + v_k}{2} \hspace{2cm} 
$$ where $\forall k \in \{1, ..., N\}$ and $(u_k,v_k)$ is a pair as showed above. (or should we define $\mathcal{T}$ as the convex hull of these points ... ? )
Then we claim:
$$ 
\mathcal{P} \cap \mathcal{Q} \subseteq \mathcal{T}
$$
Attempt:
I have made some 2d drawings and it seems true to me:

In particular in the above picture, let $\mathcal{P}, \mathcal{Q}$ and $\mathcal{T}$ be the red, blue and green polytopes respectively. Then the intersection of red and blue (the grey area) seems to be included in the green polytope. I think the reason for the 2d case is that in the following setup  the intersection of the crossing thick black lines is always below the red line (connecting the centers of the thin lines).
Question:
Is the main claim true in the general $\mathbb{R}^n$ setup?
Edit after Pranay's answer
It seems (as shown by Pranay) that the description of the problem so far is not sufficient to enforce the main claim. We therefore add:

The lines formed by every pair $(u_k,v_k)$ intersect in a point inside $\mathcal{P} \cap \mathcal{Q}$.


What is $\mathcal P_2$?

Sorry ... initally I had $\mathcal{P}_1, \mathcal{P}_2, \mathcal{P}_3$ what now is $\mathcal{P}, \mathcal{Q}, \mathcal{T}$. I thought I have replaced everywhere ... please feel free to modify or tell me where it appears

It appears in the first paragraph. Also, in item 2, did you mean to write $u_k\in \mathcal U$, etc.?

Thank you alot for helping making the post more clear. On item 2 what I meant is that the vertex $u_k$ of $\mathcal{P}$ is inside the polytope $\mathcal{Q}$ . Perhaps the drawing can help with the idea: the main idea is that for every pair of vertices $(u_k, v_k)$ one vertex is also in the other polytope.

Ah I see, thanks for the clarification: you should change it to either ... or ..., currently it is either ... either ....

My counterexample works even with this new condition (or maybe I didn't interpret it correctly). Also, please don't edit the question after it has been answered, which could invalidate the answer. If you want to add more restrictions that might invalidate the existing answers, you should accept the existing answers (if they are helpful and answer the original question) and ask a new question.

@Pranay I do apologize for (slightly) modifying the question. I even gave credit to your answer, but I cannot repost 99% of the question with a small modification, can I? Back to  your counter example: let $(u_1, v_1)$ and $(u_2,v_2)$ the pair of vertices where $M$ is the intersection of the lines formed by $(u_1, u_2) \cap (v_1, v_2)$. What I require now is the line formed by $(u_1,v_1)$ and the line by $(u_2, v_2)$ should intersect some small ball inside $\mathcal{P} \cap \mathcal{Q}$. Your example has them meeting some place outside $\mathcal{P} \cap \mathcal{Q}$

Here's a counterexample to your claim in $\mathbb R^2$. The point labelled $M$ is contained in the intersection of the red and blue polygons but not in the green polygon.


Nice example! I just now realize, that my description of the problem does not enforce everything! Basically your example would be enough to answer my question in the current form, although I just need to add that the lines formed by the pair $(u_k,v_k)$ should all intersect in a small ball inside $\mathcal{P} \cap \mathcal{Q}$

Thank you alot for helping me formulate what I really want ...
